# CakePHP : How to access $this->set(array('fruit' => 'orange', 'vegetable' => 'kale')); in controller

Tags: arrays, cakephp, this

I am a new in CakePHP and I am looking for some code, I have been downloaded function which looks like below:

```
$this->set(array('fruit' => 'orange', 'vegetable' => 'kale'));
```

In the code, the array variables are accessed in another controller function using this method:

```
$varsSet = $this->viewVars;
echo $varsSet['vegetable'];
```

What I would like to do access the array variables in the same function in the controller where the $this-set() statement is made, and it seems like I should be able to do so with just one line of code. I have tried all of the following:

```
echo $fruit;
echo $this->field('fruit');
echo $this->MyModel->$fruit;
echo $this->MyModel->field('fruit');
```

And all of these throw parse, undefined variable, or variable not found errors. What would be the simplest/most proper way to access the variable within the same function in the controller?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function $this->set() in the controller is used to pass variables from the controller to the view.

I.e.

If you have:

```
$this->set('fruit' => array('orange', 'vegetable' => 'kale'));
```

Then in the associated view you can access the array directly as

print_r($fruit);

If you want to use fruit variable in the controller, then you have to assign it to the var i.e.:

```
$fruits = array('orange', 'vegetable' => 'kale');
$this->set('fruit', $fruits);
```

But your question is not very clear what do you want to achieve with this.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...I was wondering if I just needed to create the variable then use it as needed in the controller and pass it to $this-set(), and this answers my question, thanks!

Comment: `$this->set('fruit' => $fruits)` won't work because it has syntax errors. Use `$this->set('fruit', $fruits)` instead.